# Unit testing a controller in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, controller

```
public Double Invert(Double? id)
{
    return (Double)(id / id);
}
```

I have done this for this test but fails please can anyone help with this cos just started with unit testing

```
/* HINT:  Remember that you are passing Invert an *integer* so
 * the value of 1 / input is calculated using integer arithmetic. 
 * */
//Arrange
var controller = new UrlParameterController();
int input = 7;
Double expected = 0.143d;
Double marginOfError = 0.001d;

//Act
var result = controller.Invert(input);

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result, marginOfError);

/* NOTE  This time we use a different Assert.AreEqual() method, which
 * checks whether or not two Double values are within a specified
 * distance of one another.  This is a good way to deal with rounding
 * errors from floating point arithmetic.  Without the marginOfError 
 * parameter the assertion fails.
 * */
```

Comment: I don't see a question please be more specific with your post.

Comment: This appears to be more about floating point arithmetic than unit testing. What are the results of the `Assert`?

Comment: Why are you using a nullable Double? Dividing by null is impossible anyway, so it will just result in a cryptic error.

Comment: @aulme:  Dividing by null is not *impossible*, it's just null http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.80).aspx "The predefined unary and binary operators and any user-defined operators that exist for value types may also be used by nullable types. These operators produce a null value if the operands are null; otherwise, the operator uses the contained value to calculate the result."   But, of course, the cast back to a non nullable type will fail.

Comment: @JayC - "System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value." You cannot use null here for id and try to divide.

Comment: @Travis: That's because of the cast back to a non nullable type, *not* because of the division. Besides reading MSDN, I've checked it in LinqPad.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19032/discussion-between-jayc-and-travis-j)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to test your controller to "invert" a value. It probably would help *if you weren't dividing a value by itself.*

The only things that can happen are:

1. you get a result of "1" (hint, hint)
2. you get "NaN"  ( 0/0 )
3. you get an cast error by passing in null.

Answer (score 0):

going through your code sample I think what you are looking for is an inverse method in the controller.

```
public Double Invert(Double? id)
{
    //replace id with 1 -- (1/id) gives you an inverse of id.  
    return (Double)(1 / id);
}
```